# Retrieving last known geolocation - Phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, html, geolocation

The following code

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getGeo_Success, getGeo_Fail, {
    enableHighAccuracy : true,
    maximumAge : Infinity,
    timeout : 15000
});
```

Retrieves the current GPS position - *BUT* - there must be a valid GPS signal (and ofcourse, the device's GPS feature should be turned on).

If we look at other applications (say, Maps on Android devices) - it knows how to retrieve the **last known** position - even if I didn't use an application that updates the geolocation *before* opening Maps - it shows my position on the map, even if I'm inside a building with no GPS signal at all.

Just to clarify: I'm not interested in the last geolocation my application retrieved, as on the next time I`ll start it, that geolocation will probably be irrelevant.

**Question is:** How can we achieve this with HTML5/Phonegap? seems like `navigator.geolocation` only knows to retrieve the current position, even though, `maximumAge` is set to `Infinity` (which means, the age of the last cached position is irrelevant, so any hit is okay (or, should be!))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANDROID SOLUTION (iPhone solution follows):**

This is neat:

I've made use of Android's native `LocationManager`, which provides a `getLastKnownLocation` function - the name says it all

Here's the relevant code

1) **Add the following java class to your application**

```
package your.package.app.app;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class GetNativeLocation implements LocationListener {
    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    private Location mostRecentLocation;

    public GetNativeLocation(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getLocation();
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        LocationManager lm = 
                        (LocationManager)mGap.
                                        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 500, this);
        mostRecentLocation = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void doInit(){
        getLocation();
    }

    public double getLat(){ return mostRecentLocation.getLatitude();}
    public double getLong() { return mostRecentLocation.getLongitude(); }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

2) **Make sure your main class looks as follows:**

```
public class App extends DroidGap {

    // Hold a private member of the class that calls LocationManager
    private GetNativeLocation gLocation;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This line is important, as System Services are not available
        // prior to initialization
        super.init();

        gLocation = new GetNativeLocation(this, appView);

        // Add the interface so we can invoke the java functions from our .js 
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(gLocation, "NativeLocation");

        try {
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

3) on your JS code, just call the native java using:

```
window.NativeLocation.doInit();
alert(window.NativeLocation.getLat());
alert(window.NativeLocation.getLong());
```

Thats all folks! :-)

**EDIT:
iPhone solution:**

I wrote a tiny Phonegap plugin that creates an interface to a custom class which is making use of iOS's native `CLLocationManager`

**1) Phonegap plugin (JS)**

```
var NativeLocation = {
    doInit: function(types, success, fail) {
        return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "NativeLocation", "doInit", types);
    },

    getLongitude: function(types, success, fail){
        return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "NativeLocation", "getLongitude", types);
    },

    getLatitude: function(types, success, fail){
        return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "NativeLocation", "getLatitude", types);
    }
}
```

**2) The objective-c class that enables us to invoke 'CCLocationManager's functions**
**NativeLocation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol NativeLocationDelegate
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface NativeLocation : CDVPlugin <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    id delegate;
    NSString* callbackID;
    CLLocationManager *lm;
    Boolean bEnabled;
    double nLat;
    double nLon;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *lm;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) Boolean bEnabled;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (void) doInit:(NSMutableArray*)arguments
                                 withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
- (void) getLatitude:(NSMutableArray*)arguments 
                                 withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options;
- (void) getLongitude:(NSMutableArray*)arguments 
                                 withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options;

@end
```

**NativeLocation.m**

```
#import "NativeLocation.h"

@implementation NativeLocation

@synthesize callbackID;
@synthesize lm;
@synthesize bEnabled;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)doInit:(NSMutableArray *)arguments 
                                 withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options{
    if (self != nil){
        self.lm = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.lm.delegate = self;
        if (self.lm.locationServicesEnabled == NO)
            bEnabled = FALSE;
        else bEnabled = TRUE;
    }

    nLat = 0.0;
    nLon = 0.0;

    if (bEnabled == TRUE)
        [self.lm startUpdatingLocation];

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult 
                                    resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK 
                                    messageAsString[@"OK"
                                    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (bEnabled == TRUE){
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult 
                               toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    } else {
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult 
                               toErrorCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
                        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
                        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NativeLocationDelegate)])
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation ];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NativeLocationDelegate)])
        [self.delegate locationError:error];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.lm release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cCoord = [location coordinate];
    nLat = cCoord.latitude;
    nLon = cCoord.longitude;

}

- (void)getLatitude:(NSMutableArray *)arguments 
                                      withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options{

    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];

    nLat = lm.location.coordinate.latitude;
    nLon = lm.location.coordinate.longitude;

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult 
                                    resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK 
                                    messageAsDouble:nLat];

    [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];

}
- (void)getLongitude:(NSMutableArray *)arguments 
                                       withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options{

    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];

    nLat = lm.location.coordinate.latitude;
    nLon = lm.location.coordinate.longitude;

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult 
                     resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDouble:nLon];

    [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];

}

@end
```

**3) And finally, invoking everything from the main .js**

```
function getLongitudeSuccess(result){
    gLongitude = result;
}

function getLatitudeSuccess(result){
    gLatitude = result;
}

function runGPSTimer(){
    var sTmp = "gps";

    theTime = setTimeout('runGPSTimer()', 1000);

    NativeLocation.getLongitude(
                                ["getLongitude"],
                                getLongitudeSuccess,
                                function(error){ alert("error: " + error); }
                                );

    NativeLocation.getLatitude(
                               ["getLatitude"],
                               getLatitudeSuccess,
                               function(error){ alert("error: " + error); }
                               );
```

Comment: keep in mind that this solution is just for android, and as i said before - you'll have to find solution natively for each device type. good luck

Answer (score 1):

In my PhoneGap/Sencha Touch 2 Application i created the function

```
function getLastKnownLocation(){
    if(typeof localStorage.lastKnownPosition == "undefined"){
        localStorage.lastKnownPosition = JSON.stringify(null);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position){
            localStorage.lastKnownPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        }
    );

    return JSON.parse(localStorage.lastKnownPosition);
}
```

So every time i call the getLastKnownLocation() i get a result immediately. It's a good workaround for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest in your `getGeo_Success` function call `setLocation([the_location])` to store it on **localStorage**.
 you can assume that each device that uses phoneGap already implements localStorage.
this way, you always have valid location there. and then just pop it whenever you need.

```
function getLocation() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('location'));
}
function setLocation(location) {
  localStorage.setItem('vibesList', JSON.stringify(vibes));
}
```

**edit:** if you want to retrive the latest place the **device** knows (not the app), you have to do it via **background** proccess that pulling the current data from the device. this is problematic approach because:

1. not all the devices allow it.
2. you will have to write your own native custom [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) to connect with
   phonegap for that.